# ERROR:Could not find or load main class sqoop-import, while sqoop-import from CDH to ADLS

Tags: azure, hadoop, cloudera-cdh, sqoop

We are trying to configure and setup Azure Data Lake with Cloudera Distribution.
Following the official documentation, I was able to do distcp, put etc from CHD to ADLS and vice-versa.

Recently I am trying to see if we can use sqoop-import to move data between data lake and sql db without spinning up a hdinsight cluster to reduce the cost involved.

```
hadoop --config /home/userTest/adl_conf sqoop-import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxx.yyyy.org:1433;username=xxxx;password=*****;database=xxxx" --table TEST_SQOOP --target-dir adl://xxxx.azuredatalakestore.net/some/path/toPUT
```

I already placed the files in /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop/lib folder:

```
ls -lrt /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop/lib

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   30 Mar 28 19:47 sqoop-1.4.6.jar -> /opt/sqoop/lib/sqoop-1.4.6.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   30 Mar 28 19:47 sqoop-tools.jar -> /opt/sqoop/lib/sqoop-tools.jar
```

Still not sure what am I missing, any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class sqoop-import

Comment: Try to echo SQOOP_HOME and check whether you are getting the location of the libs where you have placed the jars

Comment: I resolved this issue, problem was I had created incorrect symlinks which caused this issue, reverting the changes and retrying it resolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are not enabling sqoop to use azure data lake.
Rather Temporary Workaround is:

> use hdfs path instead of ADLs and do distcp from hdfs to ADLS